# For each order calculate total calories

Tags: mysql

I know that this is a noobie question but I really need help.

If I make a table that is like this.

| OrderNo. | Food | Calories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fries | 400 kcals |
| 1 | Chicken | 327 kcals |
| 1 | Thighs | 454 kcals |
| 2 | Rice | 291 kcals |
| 2 | Meat | 167 kcals |

I need to know for each order what is the there total calories
like this

| OrderNo. | Calories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1181 kcals |
| 2 | 458 Kcals |

So what to do? I need help.

So.
I tried to make both of them variables but it didn't work out

Comment: Use `SUM(calories)` and `GROUP BY OrderNo`.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: It seems like a design flaw to store numeric data that you want to sum as character data (with the units). When you are summing do you need to handle different units? If not, why store the units? If so, please explain all the possible units.

Comment: Is your `Calories` column a varchar? If so you might want to fix that first. If you need the `kcals` portion, put it in a different column. It will be more complicated and will take longer to execute if you try to sum strings than it will be with numeric data types.

Comment: Ok, can you write the full code? @Barmar

Comment: Sorry for confusing @Jesse but I wrote the kcals in the data base they are just numbers

Comment: @MohamedHani If I did that, I would be doing your homework for you. I gave you all the hints you should need.